# Check for New Mail of specific Mailbox/Folder Applescript

Tags: macos, email, applescript, imap

OSx 10.8.5 Mail 6.6 -
Looked online for years trying to find the REAL solution to this issue. Have IMAPed gmail account. Trying to check for mail in a specific folder/mailbox, however Mac Mail always checks all mailboxes regardless of specifying the specific folder.

Currently using a system events work around to select the mailbox via the favorites shortcut key (limited to 9 possible shortcuts/mailboxes). However I would like a more unlimited and direct solution. See typical code below.

```
tell application "Mail"
    check for new mail of mailbox "Mailbox/Folder Name" of account "Account Name"
        repeat until (background activity count) = 0
            delay 10
        end repeat
end tell
```

Any ideas? 
Thank you.

Comment: Does this script still work for you? When I try to use `background activity count` I get an error message, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74249201/applescript-mail-apps-property-background-activity-count-is-broken

Comment: Sorry, haven't used in years and we are way past OS 10.8

Comment: The same code SHOULD still work, but I just get an error message. Am interested in if others have the same problem.